# How do you find the norm of a complex vector

Tags: vectors

How would I go about finding the norm of a complex vector, for instance:

$$\|(2x+3ix)+(3y+2iy)\|$$

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ scalars or vectors? What is the vector space in question here? Is the scalar field for the vector space $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @MPW I'm assuming $x$ and $y$ represent the unit vectors in the $\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$ directions

Comment: Shaktal is right. The question I was given is to just find the norm of |2z+3iz| where z= x+iy and doing the stuff inside gets me to what was in the original post.

Comment: So the question remains, what is the vector space, and what is the norm? Is the space $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: Not quite sure about what you mean by the vector space as my professor didn't really explain too much and isn't the norm the same as magnitude? or the modulus.

Comment: The answer posted by "Thursday" below seems correct to me, based on your responses. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you actually want $|2z+3iz|$, the modulus of this complex number. Since the modulus is multiplicative, that would be 
$$|2z+3iz| = |2+3i|\,|z|=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}|z|$$ 
You can simplify the square root. About $|z|$ we don't have any information.

Comment: Judging from OP's responses to my comments, I think your answer is correct. +1 for fathoming the question ;)